# jquery form submit event not work after overlay

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog, overlay

I am attemmpting to "stall" the form submit event by inserting a modal overlay. If the user closes this overlay the form submittion should continue.

The overlay is foring when the form is submitted and the close callback on the modal overlay is firing but I cannot get the form to either continue submitting or re-submit.

I have tried many options from preventDefault through return but nothing seems to work. The logical flow seems to be on point.

```
var $form = $('form[name="myForm"]');
$form.submit(function(evt){
    $('#notify').popup({ 
      'autoopen': true, 
      onClose: function(myModal){ 
          if ($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
              console.log('checked');
          } else {
              console.log('not checked');
          }
        $form.submit();
        return true;    
      } 
    });
    return false;    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aSvsL/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var $form = $('form[name="myForm"]');
    $form.submit(function(evt){
        $('#notify').popup({ 
          'autoopen': true, 
          onClose: function(myModal){ 
              if ($('#myCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
                  console.log('checked');
              } else {
                  console.log('not checked');
              }
            $form.addClass('processed').submit();
            return true;    
          } 
        });
        return $form.hasClass('processed');    
    });
});
```